# RaiseError (PERL, DBI) equivalent for unixODBC C API?

Tags: c, perl, dbi, unixodbc

I have a problem executing some stored procedures/functions in INFORMIX DB. I tried with different clients and they were all the same - no one detects errors on executing, instead of this - return empty responses. And this does not work for me.

Finally, I found that `PERL DBI` has the option to set `RaiseError`, something like:

```
{  PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 }
```

And this works perfect. But is there such equivalent (I couldn't find anything, unfortunately) for the `unixODBC C API` lib?

---

In addition: I tried the same query with `isql` and it's the same! No errors, just empty result :\ Maybe it could be some option, that should be configured (in `odbc.ini`, I guess..) ?

---

**EDIT**: Okay, here are some more details:
**Version: unixODBC 2.3.0**

```
CREATE FUNCTION "test".NOK_func_k() RETURNING LVARCHAR(1000);
set debug file to '/home/directory_does_not_exists/unknown.log';
trace off;
trace on;
trace off;
return 'result is set here';
END FUNCTION;

CREATE PROCEDURE "test".NOK_proc_k(pDummy SMALLINT)
set debug file to '/home/directory_does_not_exists/unknown.log';
trace off;
trace on;
LET pDummy = 2;
trace off;
END PROCEDURE;
```

And the results from `isql` and `ODBC C API` are the same. Here's more info about the `C API`:

```
Executing: execute procedure NOK_proc_k(1)
retcode = SQL_ERROR     SQL_SUCCEEDED( retcode ) = 0
--------------------------------------------------
Executing: execute function NOK_func_k()
retcode = SQL_SUCCESS       SQL_SUCCEEDED( retcode ) = 1
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Executing: execute function NOK_proc_k(1)
retcode = SQL_ERROR     SQL_SUCCEEDED( retcode ) = 0
--------------------------------------------------
Executing: execute procedure NOK_func_k()
retcode = SQL_SUCCESS       SQL_SUCCEEDED( retcode ) = 1
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Executing: call NOK_proc_k(1)
retcode = SQL_ERROR     SQL_SUCCEEDED( retcode ) = 0
--------------------------------------------------
Executing: call NOK_func_k()
retcode = SQL_SUCCESS       SQL_SUCCEEDED( retcode ) = 1
```

All calls to `SQLMoreResults` return `SQL_NO_DATA`, all `SQLFetch` return `SQL_ERROR`.

Summary - all calls to wrong procedures are fine - error is returned. But if this error is in stored *function* - no error is detected; instead of this - EMPTY string is returned. Outch!

`SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO` is **not** returned anywhere. And it's like this for many other errors (not all, of course, that's just an example here)

---

And even more! Procedure or function like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "test".nok_proc_k_2() RETURNING LVARCHAR(1000);
DEFINE vNotDefined VARCHAR(10);
LET vNotDefined = current;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Does not return any error, while a Aqua DB studio returns

```
Converted value does not fit into the allotted space
```

---

### ANSWER:

I'll accept bohica'S answer, as it's correct and it answers right about the `PERL DBI` part. Also, he really helped me (the hit with `strace`).

Anyway, the real solution is not here. I have posted it in the related question, that is more specific and isolated about the particular case: [The same error is detected in stored **procedure**, but not in stored **function**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843403/the-same-error-is-detected-in-stored-procedure-but-not-in-stored-function)

Comment: I cannot tell what is supposed to work and what isn't. All your procs and funcs are named nok_something. Calling nok_func_k() seems to return a success - fine, but executing procedure nok_func_k() succeeds and yet there is no such procedure? Also "if this error is in stored function - EMPTY string is returned" - where? if a function/procedure errors surely you don't expect them to return actual values. I cannot help any further without a specific example of what procedure/function you have, how you called it, what happened and what you expected.

Comment: @bohica - I have posted the `NOK_func_k` and `NOK_proc_k` bodies.. One of them is procedure, the other is function. I have posted how they are created. Also, I have posted how they are executed: `Executing: ....` + the results. I don't understand what more information I should post.. `NOK_proc_k` is procedure with error inside. And the error is detected, so I don't expect it to return anything. As you have quoted me - "if this error is in stored function - EMPTY string is returned" - see, I'm talking about FUNCTION, so, I mean `nok_func_k`.

Comment: @bohica - The one, that succeeds all the time is `nok_func_k` and it's a **function**, not a procedure. But it has the same body, as the procedure (`NOK_proc_k`), it's just declared as function and returns a string. Note how `NOK_func_k` has e return at the end: `return 'result is set here';`. And as the error is not detected, `SQLExecute` returns `SQL_SUCCESS` and the returned string is NOT `"result is set here"`, but it's `""`. Which part I don't explain ok..? :\

Comment: Also, executing `call NOK_func_k()` from `Aqua Data Studio` and the same fro `PERL DBI`, the error is detected: `Cannot open DEBUG file for SPL routine trace.` ..

Comment: @bohica - you can see my related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843403/the-same-error-is-detected-in-stored-procedure-but-not-in-stored-function It's more clear (or at least I hope so), it's isolated and without unnecessary information.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So we now know NOK_func_k should fail with "Cannot open DEBUG file" and I could not know that before. Run your Perl calling the NOK_func_k and showing it fails but turn logging on in unixODBC. You do this by adding an [ODBC] section to the top of your odbcinst.ini file and adding two lines under it "Trace=yes" and "TraceFile=/tmp/unixodbc.log". Then we'll see where the error is detected in ODBC trace.

Comment: @bohica - it's interesting, that I have these already set, but no trace file is created in `/tmp/` :\

Comment: You need to ensure it is set in the right file. Run odbcinst -j and it tells you which file/dir unixODBC is using for the system ini file (odbcinst.ini). The you must have: [ODBC]\nTrace=yes\nTraceFile=/tmp/unixodbc.log at the top. If you don't get a trace it could be permissions or you are not using the unixODBC you think you are.

Comment: @bohica - it was in the right file, but not at the right place. It was in my driver's section, not in [ODBC]. Fixed :).  Now the file is created, but it's empty all the time, no matter what I execute.. :D

Comment: In the case I don't know assuming you have disk space. You could strace it and look for where the file is opened and see what happens on that file descriptor but we are getting into dark waters now.

Comment: @bohica - if I set nTrace=yes or nTrace=on - nothing happens. When I set it to 1 (nTrace=1) file is created, but empty :D Damn :\ And there's enough space, it's something else. I think I'll try `strace`, it's high time to learn how to use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that RaiseError in Perl does is say that when a DBD, like DBD::ODBC sees an error DBI will call any registered error handlers and call die with that error (depending on what the error handler returned). It is still up to the DBD to signal the error to DBI via set_err method.

I presume your Perl was using DBD::ODBC. DBD::ODBC will simply check the return status of every ODBC API it calls and if it is SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO it calls DBIs set_err saying it is a warning and if it is !SQL_SUCCEEDED it calls set_err saying there is an error (there are some exceptions like SQL_NO_DATA which is not always an error).

If you are saying your Perl dies with the error you are expecting but your C code does not then you must not be checking an ODBC API return or perhaps (since you mention procedures) you are not ensuring you call SQLMoreResults in a loop after SQLExecute on the SQL to call the procedure. Bear in mind some databases execute each insert/select/update in a procedure one at a time and in ODBC you need to call SQLMoreResults to move through each one. If you don't do that your procedure had not completed and hence you may not have hit the error.

Comment: Well, I tried with `SQLExecDirect` and `SQLExecute` and both return `SQL_SUCCESS` :( So, respectively, `SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLExecute( stmt ))` returns true :\ That's what worries me, But I haven't tried `SQLMoreResults` yet.

Comment: It's interesting, that executing the same with `isql` does not give me any errors, again. So, I guess it could be some configurable option?

Comment: isql does not call SQLMoreResults

Comment: If you want I could show you what DBD::ODBC does ODBC-wise. Just set DBI_TRACE=15=x.log and export it then rerun your Perl. You'll get loads out that will give you a clue. Alternatively, assuming you are using unixODBC driver manager you can enable tracing of all ODBC calls in that.

Comment: "isql does not call SQLMoreResults" - Yes it does

Comment: ok, it didn't used to and in Kiril's case we don't know what version of unixODBC he is using so it could still explain why isql does not show an error for his procedure.

Comment: at bohica and @Nick Gorham - I just added some tests to illustrate what I mean. + added version. Please, review the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: See my edit (the "ANSWER" part, not to repeat it here :) ). Thanks anyway! :) +1 and accepted.