# The same error is detected in stored **procedure**, but not in stored **function**

Tags: c, stored-procedures, error-handling, informix, unixodbc

This question is related to my previous one: [RaiseError (PERL, DBI) equivalent for unixODBC C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679261/raiseerror-perl-dbi-equivalent-for-unixodbc-c-api)

As I isolated the problem later, I'll post new question, that is more specific, isolated and without unnecessary information.

---

Version: **unixODBC 2.3.0**
lib: **unixODBC - C API**

Suppose I have a ***stored FUNCTION***:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "test".func() RETURNING LVARCHAR(1000);
set debug file to '/home/directory_does_not_exists/unknown.log';
trace off;
trace on;
trace off;
return 'result is set here';
END FUNCTION;
```

And ***the same*** body, but in ***stored PROCEDURE***:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "test".proc(pDummy SMALLINT)
set debug file to '/home/directory_does_not_exists/unknown.log';
trace off;
trace on;
LET pDummy = 2;
trace off;
END PROCEDURE;
```

As you can see, they are absolutely the same. The path to debug file is wrong, so error is expected. When I execute `call func()` from `Aqua Data Studio` the error is detected:

```
Cannot open DEBUG file for SPL routine trace
```

It's the same for `call proc(1)`.

***BUT*** when I execute these 2 calls through unixODBC (using `SQLExecute`),

```
execute procedure proc(1);
```

returns `SQL_ERROR` (which is expected and fine), while

```
execute function func();
```

returns `SQL_SUCCESS`.. ***BUT*** `'result is set here'` is ***not*** returned, empty string (`''`) is returned, instead..

Executing `call func()` gives the same results, as `execute function func();`

Calling `SQLMoreResults` returns `SQL_NO_DATA`, `SQLFetch` returns `SQL_ERROR`.

Any ideas?

Comment: why is this question tagged C?

Comment: Because it's about `unixODBC`, the `C API` ? Sorry, I have forgotten to mention it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - thanks **a lot** to @Jonathan Leffler(for the hint with `SQLIDEBUG=2:xyz` + `sqliprint` and testing on his machine) and @bohica (for the hint with `strace` ) for the support! That really helped me to find the real problem and solve it! +1 from me for both.
Unfortunately, the answer was not in their posts, that's why I'll answer it my own.

---

### Summary:

`SQLPrepare` and `SQLExecute` fail **sometimes** on **some** errors, but not all. When stored **procedure** is used, these functions catch more errors. Unfortunately, the situation is different with stored **functions**.

How I catch the errors now? If `SQLExecute` is successfull, I call `SQLNumResultCols` - that's normal. After that, I call `SQLFetch` which is also expected. BUT, as `SQLFetch` may fail for many reasons (for example, it always fails on stored procedures), it's error is ignored. And there's a `while` like

```
if ( SQLNumResultCols( stmt, &nAllCols ) != SQL_SUCCESS )
// ...

int nSucceededFetches = 0; // added now, see below why
while ( SQL_SUCCEEDED( SQLFetch( stmt ) ) )
{
    ++nSucceededFetches; // added now, see below why
    /* bla bla */ 
}
```

And **here's the key** - add additional check:

```
if( 0 == nSucceededFetches && nColumns > 0 )
```

which says - if there **are** returned columns **and fetch fails on the FIRST call**, then something's wrong. Then I have

```
while ( SQL_SUCCESS == SQLError( 0, 0, stmt, szSqlState, &nNativeError, szError, 500, &nErrorMsg ) )
{ /* bla bla */ }
```

---

And everything's fine. I still don't understand why `SQLExecute` returns `SQL_SUCCESS` (NOT even `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO` ..), but it doesn't matter.

Comment: If what you say is true then I think it is a bug in the driver. SQLExecute should should fail SQL_SUCCEEDED. DBD::ODBC probably shows the error because it calls SQLError after SQLExecute regardless of whether SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLExecute()) is true or not. The comment in the code says "Call dbd_error regardless of the value of rc so we can get any status messages that are desired.". I cannot remember if I wrote that bit of DBD::ODBC or not. You can find it at http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MJEVANS/DBD-ODBC-1.31/dbdimp.c

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a driver bug. Or I do something terribly wrong :) I see, thanks for the reference. I do something like this now, as in `dbdimp.c` - "check just in case". The problem is, that I'm not sure if this will work always, or sometimes I could get some "false alarm" error. But anyway, the important thing here is, that works for now. Thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Informix but the simple examples I've tried with Perl DBD::ODBC and also from isql (written in C) all return an error:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $h = DBI->connect();
eval {
    $h->do(q/drop function fmje/);
};

$h->do(<<'EOS');
create function fmje (@p1 as int)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @a int;

    set @a = 'fred';
    return @p1;
end;
EOS

my $s = $h->prepare(q/{? = call fmje(?)/);
$s->bind_param_inout(1, \my $x, 10);
$s->bind_param(2, 1);
$s->execute;
print "return is ", ($x ? $x : "undef"), "\n";



isql -v baugi sa easysoft
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> {call fmje(1)}
[22005][unixODBC][Easysoft][SQL Server Driver 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'fred' to data type int.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute
SQL>
```

Informix must work differently for functions or perhaps you are not using generic ODBC via Aqua Data Studio.

If you see the error from Perl as you say in your other post then do as I recommended there and add:

```
[ODBC]
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/tmp/unixodbc.log
```

to the top of your odbcinst.ini file and run the Perl. Then show us the lines from the log from the error. Then repeat with isql so we can compare the ODBC calls.

Comment: Whoa! Nice! There's a small progress. I created the same function and executed it through `isql` - NO ERROR detected.. Or at least - executed fine. BUT, now I see where this empty string comes from - it's the error description! Wow. So, when I run `isq` with `-v` (verbose), the returned string is NOT empty, but it contains the error description - in this case: `[37000][Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Character to numeric conversion error`. BUT, it's executed fine, and error is NOT shown (as with your execution) - NO `ERROR: Could not SQLExecute` in my `isql` and `INFORMIX` DB.

Comment: I found the solution (you can check my answer). Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This may be something to do with the server version you are using (unlikely, but possible), or to do with the API you are using.  When I test with IDS 11.70.FC2 on MacOS X 10.7 using (my) sqlcmd program build with ESQL/C (CSDK) 3.70.FC2, I get:

```
$ sqlcmd -c -d stores -e begin -xf x1.sql -e 'execute procedure proc(2)' \
         -e 'execute function func()' 
+ CREATE FUNCTION "test".func() RETURNING LVARCHAR(1000);
set debug file to '/home/directory_does_not_exists/unknown.log';
trace off;
trace on;
trace off;
return 'result is set here';
END FUNCTION;
+ CREATE PROCEDURE "test".proc(pDummy SMALLINT)
set debug file to '/home/directory_does_not_exists/unknown.log';
trace off;
trace on;
LET pDummy = 2;
trace off;
END PROCEDURE;
+ execute procedure proc(2)
SQL -648: Cannot open DEBUG file for SPL routine trace.
SQLSTATE: IX000 at /dev/stdin:0
+ execute function func()
SQL -648: Cannot open DEBUG file for SPL routine trace.
at /dev/stdin:0
$
```

As you can see, both `func()` and `proc()` correctly report an error in ESQL/C.  So, the problem is almost certainly in the client-side code - in the ODBC driver and the way it is handling the errors, or in the code calling the ODBC driver.

#### How to isolate the problem more?

Run your test with `SQLIDEBUG=2:xyz` in the environment.  Then, find the file with a names starting `xyz_` (I got `xyz_35424_0_819800`, for example) and run `sqliprint` on it.  That will show you whether the server is generating the error message twice.

I got two packets similar to this in the one trace:

```
S->C (12)               Time: 2011-07-28 00:28:02.41736
    SQ_ERR
        SQL error..........: -648
        ISAM/RSAM error....: 0
        Offset in statement: 0
        Error message......: "" [0]
    SQ_EOT
```

If you see the two packets with the -648 error, then you know the problem is in the way the client is handling the error.  If you don't see the two errors, then I'm very curious to see what is going on.

Comment: Hmmm, nice. Yes, you're right. This works(export the variable, execute through `isql` and then `sqliprint xyz`) and I receive the same error (-648). Also, if I execute the call with `dbaccess`, directly from the INFORMIX server, I receive the error again. The problem is, that `isql` (it's the same with my simple `C` app), does not show me  any errors and empty string is returned, instead(`func`). That's strange. This makes me think, that this could be something with the configuration or I don't know. Maybe some additional option in `odbc.ini`, `odbcinst.ini`, `sqlhosts` or I don't know :\

Comment: Ha! Nice! I understood where this empty string (that is returned) comes from..it's the error description. Or something like this. What I mean is, that when I execute the call using `isql`, empty string is returned, no error is detected. BUT when I start `isql` with `-v` (verbose), **NO** error is detected again (executed successfully), **BUT** the empty string is no more empty string, it's set to `Cannot open DEBUG file for SPL routine trace` which is expected. The problem is, that the execution is still fine and ERROR is not shown (just the error message)

Comment: I don't know if `unixODBC` has such option (to set verbose), but even if it does, if error code is not returned, I can't rely on error messages :\ I'll continue with my research, we have some progress (small, unfortunately, but progress). Any ideas are welcome :) Thanks!

Comment: The CSDK I have is clientsdk.3.70.UC2DE.LINUX.tar and the unixODBC version is 2.3.0 - both are last versions. Do you have installed `isql` (it comes with the CSDK, if I'm not wrong)? If so, could you, please, run the calls in you isql? BTW, I used `finderr` for `-648` and it's found, described, etc.(on both - client and server machines) So, it's not some mysterious error..

Comment: I found the solution (you can check my answer). Thanks a lot for the help!